# What is the space complexity of this code snippet

Tags: java, algorithm

the original question is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/description/)
What is the space complexity of the following code snippet? I know the time complexity is `O(log(m+n))`. I think the space complexity is also `O(log(m + n))` but I'm not certain.

```
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    int lens1, lens2, sumLens;
    lens1 = nums1.length;
    lens2 = nums2.length;
    sumLens = nums1.length + nums2.length;
    if (sumLens % 2 != 0) {
        return findKthSmallest(nums1, 0, lens1, nums2, 0, lens2, sumLens / 2 + 1);
    } else {
        return (findKthSmallest(nums1, 0, lens1, nums2, 0, lens2, sumLens / 2 + 1) + findKthSmallest(nums1, 0, lens1, nums2, 0, lens2, sumLens / 2)) / 2.0;
    }
}

private int findKthSmallest(int[] nums1, int begin1, int end1, int[] nums2, int begin2, int end2, int k) {
    if (end1 > end2) {
        return findKthSmallest(nums2, begin2, end2, nums1, begin1, end1, k);
    }
    if (end1 == 0) {
        return nums2[begin2 + k - 1];
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        return Math.min(nums1[begin1], nums2[begin2]);
    }

    int partA = Math.min(k / 2, end1);
    int partB = k - partA;
    if (nums1[begin1 + partA - 1] == nums2[begin2 + partB - 1]) {
        return nums1[begin1 + partA - 1];
    } else if (nums1[begin1 + partA - 1] > nums2[begin2 + partB - 1]) {
        return findKthSmallest(nums1, begin1, end1, nums2, begin2 + partB, end2 - partB, k - partB);
    } else {
        return findKthSmallest(nums1, begin1 + partA, end1 - partA, nums2, begin2, end2, k - partA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that's the complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At an initial glance, since no auxiliary data structures are used, it would seem that this algorithm is in-place and therefore has O(1) space complexity.

-- EDIT --

So for each recursive call a constant size block of data will be added to the call stack, increasing the space by the number of calls which will be O(lg(m+n)).

Comment: But this is a recursive call. Spaces are calculated for how many times the method gets called.

Comment: That is true, I do not know if java will perform this optimization but since the calls are tail recursive there is no need to save the stack frame therefore all additional calls will not increase space used. But you are right, if this is not the case in java then the total space complexity would be O(1) + (number of calls) which would seem to result in your original O(lg(m+n)).